# Setting number to column from counter table in same transaction

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table where I keep a counter acording to a "document_type"

```
TABLE: document_counter
document_type = "general"
last_number = 100

TABLE: document
document_id
document_number
document_type
description
...
```

What is the correct way to handle the transaction if I need to create a new "document" but put in "document_number" the next available number? Should I do two transactions or how?

Comment: You want to create a new document, use the document_counter.last_number value as document_number, and increment the document_counter?

Comment: Yes, but if posible in one transaction. What I dont want is to have the document_counter.last_number increased if theres any problem during the save and the transaction rollbacked

Answer (score 1):

[John Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508560/john-watson) is right, a transaction should be what you need.

Depending on the dbms you are using, if you start by updating the document counter and then read the new number, that row can be locked for read.

Only after you commit the current transaction will the next transaction have access to it, therefore getting the correct next number.

Answer (score 0):

You start a transaction, do all of your updates, then if everything worked, commit; otherwise, rollback. Pseudo-code:

```
 start transaction;
 select last_number from document_counter;
 insert into document (...) values (...);
 update document_counter set last_number = last_number + 1;
 commit;
```

Comment: But what happend if while " insert into document (...) values (...);" other transaction also Selected the last_number?